# System does not shut down. What can I do?

Tags: shutdown

I am using Ubuntu OS for one year. Currently I am using Ubuntu 12.04LTS. When I click the shutdown button I am directed back to the login screen instead. It has become difficult to shut down.

What can I do to enable shutdown again?

Comment: Are you able to suspend or hibernate, @Karthikeyan.k? If not, have a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/181078/i-cant-get-suspend-hibernate-and-shutdown-to-work-in-ubuntu-12-04?lq=1

Comment: Is there anyway to shut it down?

Comment: Are you logged into any other virtual terminal, at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

as I came to know from the google , it happens some times and will be solved by the updates . Until that ,you can shutdown your PC from the terminal with

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

Here's some background info: [Shutdown/suspend/hibernate not working correctly](https://askubuntu.com/q/73365/89042)

Comment: snow do you have a link you found in google? I am interested in reading it.

Comment: @Private for clarity .

Comment: @Private The link has been added if you are still interested.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> (or F2, F3, F4, etc.) to open a text terminal.

Login, using a user and password with **sudo** rights.

Then just type:

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

***This forces a halt and power-down.***

Answer (score 0):

Use  `poweroff` command or `init 0` to shutdown the system